# Is getting cosmetic items from crates gender specific?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG you can get some clothing items which would only make sense if playing a female character (e.g.: miniskirts, corset...).

Is there any difference in chance of getting them from crates depending of having a male or female avatar? Can I get them at all with a male character?
Can a male character even wear them or are they not equipable then? (I don't remember that I ever saw a male character wearing a skirt in the game so far)

Comment: Why do you think miniskirts and corsets only make sense if playing a female?

Comment: @stoop: I did not wanted to discriminate anyone, lets say it is very unusal for not fun shooter games which simulate a fight to death that men wear such clothes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The items that you receive when you open crates are randomly determined based on pre-set odds for each item. Each player has the exact same odds for each eligible item, regardless of their player avatar's sex. If you are interested in finding out what the exact odds are for the crates, they have been publishing them in the patch notes along with each update that adds a new crate. For instance you can see the [Desperado and Biker crates drop rates here](http://steamcommunity.com/games/578080/announcements/detail/1576688908203724690).

As for who can wear what, according to the [PUBG community coordinator](https://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/160854-new-crate-system-faq/):

> **Can male characters wear skirts?**
>   All outfits can be worn by both genders in PUBG.

[image: Combat Skirt]
<sup>The Combat Skirt, better airflow, less restrictive than pants, and you get to show-off dem legs.</sup>

Comment: W.r.t. those "kilts": do any of the crates have disposable razors?

Comment: @davidbak Nope, but the male Avatar's all have silky smooth legs. Must be to let you swim faster....